# Dropzone previews not displaying in preview zone

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I'm progromatically implementing dropzone into a form using Matias Meno's tutorial here: https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/Combine-normal-form-with-Dropzone.

The previews are failing to properly display in the preview-zone div and I'm not sure why.

HTML:

```
      <form id="my-awesome-dropzone" action="/uploads" class="dropzone">
            <fieldset name="contact-form-fieldset">
                <legend><h1>Request Services</h1></legend>
                <ul>
                    <li class="contact-form-fieldset-title">Full Name</li>
                    <li><input type="text" name="name" id="contact-form-name" class="plain buffer"></li>
                    <li class="contact-form-fieldset-title">
                    <li class="contact-form-fieldset-title">Email</li>
                    <li><input type="email" name="email" id="contact-form-email" class="plain buffer"></li>
                    <li class="contact-form-fieldset-title">Phone</li>
                    <li><input type="text" name="phone" id="contact-form-phone" class="plain buffer"></li>
                    <li class="contact-form-fieldset-title">Describe the problem with your device</li>
                    <li>
                        <textarea class="plain buffer" id="styled" name="styled-textarea"></textarea>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                          <div class="dropzone-previews"></div> <!-- this is were the previews should be shown. -->
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div id="contact-form-fieldset-button">
                <button type="submit">Submit data and files!</button>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <p>In a hurry? Call 632-345-674</p>
        </form>
```

```
     <script src="../js/dropzone.js"></script>
     <script src="../js/uploader.js"></script>
```

The uploader.js file contains Matias' original code:

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = { // The camelized version of the ID of the form element

// The configuration we've talked about above
autoProcessQueue: false,
uploadMultiple: true,
parallelUploads: 100,
maxFiles: 100,

  // The setting up of the dropzone
init: function() {
  var myDropzone = this;

// First change the button to actually tell Dropzone to process the queue.
this.element.querySelector("button[type=submit]").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  // Make sure that the form isn't actually being sent.
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  myDropzone.processQueue();
});

// Listen to the sendingmultiple event. In this case, it's the sendingmultiple event instead
// of the sending event because uploadMultiple is set to true.
this.on("sendingmultiple", function() {
  // Gets triggered when the form is actually being sent.
  // Hide the success button or the complete form.
});
this.on("successmultiple", function(files, response) {
  // Gets triggered when the files have successfully been sent.
  // Redirect user or notify of success.
});
this.on("errormultiple", function(files, response) {
  // Gets triggered when there was an error sending the files.
  // Maybe show form again, and notify user of error
}); }}
```

Anybody have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: does the browser console show any error? and apart from the preview, is the file upload functionality working?

Comment: @jkris, no error. The file upload functionality half-works. The preview will show as uploaded and display, but the checkmark and the "x" both display under the  preview, instead of the checkmark displaying after the file successfully uploads.

Comment: @jkris i played around a bit and fixed the problem with the dropzone-preview improperly displaying, but now the drag-and-drop feature doesn't work.....i'm getting this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"

Answer (score 0):

Try
previewsContainer: ".dropzone-previews"